# StructureMap singleton usage (A class implementing two interface)

Tags: c#, singleton, structuremap

```
public interface IInterface1
{
}

public interface IInterface2
{
}

public class MyClass : IInterface1, IInterface2
{
}

...

ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.For<IInterface1>().Singleton().Use<MyClass>();
    x.For<IInterface2>().Singleton().Use<MyClass>();
});

var x = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IInterface1>();
var y = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IInterface2>();
```

I get two different MyClass instances with the above code. How can I get one?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the Forward<,>() registration to tell StructureMap to resolve a type using the resolution of a different type. This should do what you expect:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.For<IInterface1>().Singleton().Use<MyClass>();
    x.Forward<IInterface1, IInterface2>();
});
```

Answer (score 14):

I would register the MyClass itself and then pull that out of the context for the Use statements of the individual interfaces.

```
ForSingletonOf<MyClass>().Use<MyClass>();

For<IInterface1>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<MyClass>());
For<IInterface2>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<MyClass>());
```

Comment: This is what worked for me! The "x.Forward" method did not work, my code could not resolve IInterface2.

Comment: @andyhammer You might have swapped the two interface. FROM is first, TO is second. I made that mistake ...

Nice solution, was thinking I had a bad design and is was not possible, but I guess other have the same issue, thank god.

Comment: I think this approach is cleaner, I don't like to couple these interfaces to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the different overloads to Use, especially Func overload. From there you can tell how StructureMap should create your instance with another object already registred.

Answer (score -4):

An `ObjectFactory` is **intended** to create multiple instances. If you want a singleton, write a singleton class (perhaps with public `IInterface1` and `IInterface2` properties as accessors).

It seems sketchily documented, but perhaps you can use a [Container](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/10/18/using-the-structuremap-container-independent-of-objectfactory.aspx) instead.

Comment: The container (either ObjectFactory or a manually created Container) can handle the object lifecycle for you - no need to implement singleton behavior yourself.