# Autofac - Resolve Service on Enum and return different types

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I know this is possible using keyed and named services which can be found here in the official documentation.

[Keyed and Named Services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html?highlight=keyed)

In the case of keyed services - If we take a look at the official example we see this.

```
builder.RegisterType<OnlineState>().Keyed<IDeviceState>(DeviceState.Online);
```

We are binding the common interface IDeviceState to the concrete class OnlineState and OnlineState will resolve out of the container if the enum Device.Online is passed.

```
var r = container.ResolveKeyed<IDeviceState>(DeviceState.Online);
```

We are bound by the methods of IDeviceState when r is resolved , but now to my question.

What if my concrete implementations such as OnlineState return unique types , methods on IDeviceState force the same return type on all concrete classes . For Example:

```
public interface IDeviceState { string GetDeviceStateInformation(); }
```

Now all my concrete classes are forced to return a string for the GetDeviceState(); method whereas different implementations might return different types.

How do take the same approach but cater for this scenario?

Example Below :

```
public class OnlineState : IDeviceState 
{   
   public string GetDeviceStateInformation() { 
     return String.empty;
     }  

}  

  public class OfflineState: IDeviceState 
{   
   public string GetDeviceStateInformation() { 
     //Im forced to use string over due to interface. 
     //But would actually like to return a int for example 
     return String.empty;
     }  
   public int GetDeviceStateInformation() { 
     //This is the actual method i want to call on the implementation class.
     //But can not due to IDeviceState
     return 5;

     }  
}
```

I would like to let autofac handle the resolving of the correct service based upon the enum but not forced to use the methods of the common interface IDeviceState.

```
var r = container.ResolveKeyed<IDeviceState>(DeviceState.Online);
//I would like result to be different types - right now result will always 
//be string but should change depending on the service that is resolved.
var result = r.GetDeviceStateInformation();
```

My Implementation on Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class DeviceStateController: Controller
{
   IIndex<DeviceState, IDeviceState> _states;

    public DeviceStateController(IIndex<DeviceState, IDeviceState> states)
    {
        _states= states;
    }
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetDeviceState(DeviceState deviceEnum)
    {
       //Must Return Different Types
        return Ok(_states[deviceEnum].GetDeviceStateInformation());
    }
```

Comment: Resolving services through `Autofac` is not related to the issue you are facing. Autofac can resolve the service using name or key.

Comment: Derived types can't change signature of interface method. Did you condisider generic interface `IDeviceState<T>`?

Comment: @KozhevnikovDmitry , Indeed I have , the problem comes in that when you inject `IIndex<DeviceState, IDeviceState> _states;` into your constructor IDeviceState will expect a type already.  like so `IIndex<DeviceState, IDeviceState<KnownType>>` , I dont know the type on constructor injection only on method level when I have the actual enum to resolve . Only the concrete class knows about the type it needs to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems I got your point. The problem is that C# requires to know all types at compile time. So you are forced to sacrifice the strong typing a little bit somewhere. Take a look on example below. I preserved generic strong typed `DeviceState` classes, however the result of `GetDeviceStateInformation()` is passed to controller by `object` reference. It is not an elegant approach, of cource, C# has its own limitations.

```
public class DeviceStateController : Controller
{
    IIndex<DeviceState, IDeviceState> _states;

    public DeviceStateController(IIndex<DeviceState, IDeviceState> states)
    {
        _states = states;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDeviceState(DeviceState deviceEnum)
    {
        //Must Return Different Types
        var result = await _states[deviceEnum].GetDeviceStateInformation();
        return Ok(result);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class DeviceStateControllerTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task GetDeviceStateTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<OnlineState>().Keyed<IDeviceState>(DeviceState.Online);
        builder.RegisterType<OfflineState>().Keyed<IDeviceState>(DeviceState.Offline);
        builder.RegisterType<DeviceStateController>();
        var container = builder.Build();
        var controller = container.Resolve<DeviceStateController>();

        // Act
        var stringResult = (OkObjectResult)await  controller.GetDeviceState(DeviceState.Online);
        var intResult = (OkObjectResult)await controller.GetDeviceState(DeviceState.Offline);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(stringResult.Value, "Online");
        Assert.AreEqual(intResult.Value, 404);
    }
}


public interface IDeviceState
{
    Task<object> GetDeviceStateInformation();
}

public interface IDeviceState<T> : IDeviceState
{
    new Task<T> GetDeviceStateInformation();
}

public abstract class DeviceState<T> : IDeviceState<T>
{
    public abstract Task<T> GetDeviceStateInformation();

    async Task<object> IDeviceState.GetDeviceStateInformation()
    {
        return await GetDeviceStateInformation();
    }
}

public class OnlineState : DeviceState<string>
{
    public override async Task<string> GetDeviceStateInformation()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult("Online");
    }
}

public class OfflineState : DeviceState<int>
{
    public override async Task<int> GetDeviceStateInformation()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(404);
    }
}

public enum DeviceState
{
    Online = 1,
    Offline = 2
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , It certainly does help my case , the only problem is I must know the type to resolve from the container like your example `var state1 = container.Resolve<IDeviceState<string>>();` , The whole reason for using keyed is that im being passed an enum and based upon that enum I am required to resolve a service which returns a type. I would have to create a method for every possible enum , resolve from container based upon that services return type which results in either if statements for every possible enum or method per enum etc etc

Comment: Its being returned to a function which will return it to a controller , im trying to avoid having to create multiple actions on the controller for each enum.

Comment: It must be able to return multiple types , ie `string` , `int32` or a strongly typed model etc  , in my case it will only be models eg `OnlineDeviceStateModel`

Comment: I have updated my original question with the controller

Comment: While this is not the most elegant way as you mentioned , using object as a crutch to return the different types certainly is just fine for my case . thank you for your time and effort . I have marked your answer as the solution to my problem.

Comment: Correct , You'll notice as soon as you make both `Task<T>` and `Task<object>` the compiler will say NO :P

Comment: Happy to help=)

Comment: Let me give that a go :)

Comment: I forgot to mark my method signature as async , slow day -.-  . Take all my internet points!

Answer (score 0):

Segregate the interface, Its one or the SOLID principles eg https://www.dotnetcurry.com/software-gardening/1257/interface-segregation-principle-isp-solid-principle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594819/how-to-manage-interface-segregation-when-using-an-ioc-container

Comment: -1 [When someone goes on Stack Overflow, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). You should place the relevant information in the answer itself.