# StructureMap singleton

Tags: ioc-container, structuremap

Are these two equivalent?

1)          var store = new DocumentStore();

```
        For<IDocumentStore>().Use(store);
```

2)          var store = new DocumentStore();

```
        For<IDocumentStore>().Singleton().Use(store);
```

or

```
        For< IDocumentStore>().AlwaysUnique().Use(store);
```

Will both of these return singleton instance of documentstore with no duplicate instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will always get singleton behavior when you provide an instance instead of just a type.

Answer (score 6):

**AlwaysUnique()** does the opposite and always creates a unique(new) instance, kind of opposite to singelton.
See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363458/structuremap-singleton-usage-a-class-implementing-two-interface)  to see how to share singeltons between two interfaces.

**Singelton()** creates the singelton. It is a Singelton for this container for this interface, in your example IDocumentStore. 
(edit): it is actually a singelton for transiently created objects for this container. Please google that term together with structure map . Generally these are the objects that are created automatically and injected into classes, but I have not seen an exact definition of this.