# register one type for two interfaces in StructureMap

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Is it possible to register ONE type for TWO interface in **StructureMap**? Look:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork { }

public interface IUnitOfWork<TSession> : IUnitOfWork { }

public class NHibernateUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork<ISession> { }
```

I want to register `NHibernateUnitOfWork` for both `IUnitOfWork` and `IUnitOfWork<TSession>` e.g. one instance of `NHibernateUnitOfWork` -per http request- be responsible for both `IUnitOfWork` and `IUnitOfWork<TSession>`. I use this registry:

```
For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<NHibernateUnitOfWork>();
For<IUnitOfWork<>>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<NHibernateUnitOfWork>();
```

But I don't know is this currect or not? Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Forward command, as demonstrated in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366838/156533

You just need to change the life cycle, if you don't want a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at that registration, I expect the container to create for both registrations a single `NHibernateUnitOfWork` within a single HTTP Context. In other words, I expect the following test to fail:

```cs
var uow1 = container.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
var uow2 = container.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork<ISession>>();
Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(uow1, uow2));
```

What you are probably after is having the container returing the same instance when resolving both `IUnitOfWork` and `IUnitOfWork<ISession>`, which would make the previous test pass.

You can change your registration to the following:

```cs
For<NHibernateUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped();
For<IUnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifeStyle())
    .Use(() => container.GetInstance<NHibernateUnitOfWork>());
For<IUnitOfWork<ISession>>().LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifeStyle())
    .Use(() => container.GetInstance<NHibernateUnitOfWork>());
```

In this case, every time you request an `IUnitOfWork`, you will be calling back into the container and request an `NHibernateUnitOfWork`, which is configured as `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped`.